# Relabel rows conditionally based on calculations

Tags: r

I have a data frame with these columns (using `str()` to print):

```
$ Height: int  135 172 170 175  ...
$ Weight: int  47 34 28 29  ...
$ answer        : chr  "Y" "M" "M" "Y" ...
```

I use this to calculate:

```
data$news[data$answer == "Y"] <- ((5 * data$Weight.) + (11 * data$Height))
data$news[data$answer == "N"] <- ((6 * data$Weight) + (55 * data$Height))
```

this will give me new column:

```
$ news        : num  28.2 37.2 54.4 50.2 50 ...
```

Then I will try to relabel as:

```
data$news[data$news > 50] <- 0
data$news[data$news <= 50] <- 1
```

but the output gives me `data$news` all as 1 (there is not a single 0, which it should not considering the values above, there should be 1s and 0s).

How come?

Also I want to relabel all "0" or "1" as "Above" or "Under" like:

```
data$news <- factor(data$news, levels = c(0,1), labels = c("Above", "Under"))
```

but it gives me:

```
$ news        : Factor w/ 2 levels "Above","Under": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
```

This problem I also do not understand, but is it because of last problem?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `ifelse`

```
data$news <- with(data, ifelse(news > 50, "Above", "Under"))
```

---

The output showed in OP's post is a `factor` class.  It shows the `levels` and integer storage values.  There is nothing to worry about.  If we need a `character` class, then wrap it with `as.character`

```
data$news <- as.character(data$news)
```